# Replacing KDE default bluetooth applet with Blueman

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kde, blueman

I've installed Blueman to use instead of the default KDE 4.3 bluetooth applet. I've added blueman-applet to KDE's startup, so that works, but when I enable bluetooth on my laptop the default applet (kbluetooth4) gets started as well.

How do I prevent this? Or better yet, how do I make it so that KDE starts blueman when I enable bluetooth, and I don't have to make it autostart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run: sudo apt-get remove kdebluetooth

Comment: I'm on Kubuntu 17.10, and it seem to have the package `kdebluetooth` neither installed nor available in the depository. Do you have an idea what I should do?

Answer (score 4):

The package for the KDE Bluetooth stack is called `bluedevil`. You can remove it using:

```
sudo apt remove bluedevil
```

To install the blueman applet just use:

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

I tested this in Kubuntu 18.04.1, the bluedevil package exists in the Ubuntu repositories since 14.04, so this should work on all versions since 14.04.

Comment: This is the correct answer as of Kubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program hooking into the HAL events. `halevt`, `ivman` and a bit of `bash` glue can go a long way. Basically every time the bluetooth device appears, launch Blueman, wait a few seconds and kill Kbluetooth4.

KDE has an interface for both managing devices and hardware stacks in System Settings on the Advanced tab. Have a look whether this is useful, I can't check for lack of Bluetooth.